# What initializer called in convenience init of UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, initializer

I often use convenience init in `UIViewController` to make custom initializer.

But I don't know what existing initializer of `UIViewController` being called when `self.init()`.

Is it `public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)`?

What is called when `self.init()` in convenience init of `UIViewController`?

```
final class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
    private var component: Component?

    convenience init(component: Component) {  // Custom initializer
       self.init()  // What is this initializer?
       self.component = component
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIViewController.init` calls `UIViewController.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`. That means that the `nibName` will be equal to the name of the class and bundle will be the main bundle.

`UIViewController.init` is just a convenience initializer. In swift this could be implemented using default parameters `UIViewController.init(nibName: String? = nil, bundle: NSBundle? = nil)` but this is an old Objective-C API and Objective-C does not have default parameters and that's why there is a separate convenience `init()`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how the `UIViewController` is instantiated.

It could be `init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)` when that is called directly through code or `init?(coder: NSCoder)` if instantiated through Interface Builder mechanisms (Storyboard Segue, Main View Controller, etc.)